# Loading a class into a function?

Tags: php, class, function, external

I`m currently working on a script, and I have the following situation.

```
function somnicefunction()
{
    require 'someexternalclass.php';
    $somevar = new SomeExternalClass();
}
```

For some reason, the above breaks the function. I'm not sure why, I haven't seen much documentation in php.net regarding this, plus google returned no real results.
Does anyone have any idea ?

Comment: What error message does this throw?

Comment: No errors whatsoever. But whatever followed the script's body to execute, it failed to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declaring the object first and then pass it as a parameter to the function:

```
require 'someexternalclass.php';
$somevar = new SomeExternalClass();
function somnicefunction(SomeExternalClass $somevar)
{
    // Do function stuff
}
```

Comment: This is a wordpress install and I'm working on a plugin, so I'd need to hack all the levels in order to pass the variable ( I presume that's you're idea )

Answer (score 2):

If you call the function more than once, you may encounter an error by trying to include the same file.

Try using `require_once()` instead. Other than that, there is nothing inherently 'illegal' about your example.

Comment: I failed to mention that I do use require_once.

Comment: Well, nothing you're doing is wrong in the eyes of PHP. Without the rest of your code it's impossible to give you a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is absolutely valid. I tested it on localhost and it works just fine. I used following piece of code:

**function.php**

```
function loadClass()
{
    include_once "include.php";
    new SomeExternalClass();
}

loadClass();
```

**include.php**

```
class SomeExternalClass {
    public function __construct( ) {
        echo "loads...";
    }
}
```

Are you sure you don't have any typo there? If you aren't getting any error, it might indicate that you haven't used the function anywhere.